# Can't access a Sqlite file on a network drive using JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, jdbc

I'm trying to access, using JDBC, a sqlite db put on a network drive, but I can't.
The drive is mapped locally with the letter "M" on my machine (running Windows 7)
I've tried with these connection strings:

```
jdbc:sqlite:M://path/to/file.db
jdbc:sqlite:\\hostname\path\to\file.db
jdbc:sqlite:\\\\hostname\path\to\file.db
```

Neither works.
It simply says "**'M:\' does not exist**" (or "**'\' does not exist**").
However the file is accessible, and I can open it using the command line.
Maybe it's a JDBC problem ?

**EDIT:** @GordThompson You're right, `jdbc:sqlite:M:/path/to/file.db` works. It turned out that the problem was because I'm trying to open this connection from Tomcat, which is running as a service, and hence doesn't have access to the mapped drives.

So now the problem is: how can I access the file using an UNC path in the connection string?
Using `jdbc:sqlite:\\hostname\path\to\file.db` (or `jdbc:sqlite:\\\\hostname\path\to\file.db`) I still get `'\\' does not exist`.

Comment: `jdbc:sqlite:M:/path/to/file.db` (no double slash) should work. Hint: Always use forward slashes for path separators, even on Windows (e.g., `jdbc:sqlite://hostname/path/to/file.db` should work, too). When Java runs on Windows it is smart enough to know that `//hostname/path` really means `\\hostname\path`.

Comment: re: edit - `jdbc:sqlite://servername/sharename/test_db.sqlite` works for me from a simple console app running within Eclipse. Verify that Tomcat is running under an account that has permission to access resources over the network. (Hint: "Network Service" should be able to read files over the network, but "Local Service" probably cannot .)

Comment: @GordThompson Great! Network Service didn't work, however a user with administrator privileges did the trick! Thank you bud!